# ROS2 twist sub linker errors

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build a node for a motor controller.
I have a timer, a `pub<custom message>` and a sub to twist.
I have added both `std_msgs` and `geometry_msgs` to both the [package.xml](https://github.com/Neuromancer2701/ROS_2_VESC_Node/blob/master/src/vesc_node/package.xml) and the [cmakelist.txt](https://github.com/Neuromancer2701/ROS_2_VESC_Node/blob/master/src/vesc_node/CMakeLists.txt).

It compiles and links if I comment out the line below:

```
subscription_ = this->create_subscription<Twist>("cmd_vel", std::bind(&VescNode::twist_callback, this, _1),cmd_vel_qos_profile);
```

Then that line is added back in I get all sorts of linking errors.
Are `std_msgs` and `geometry_msgs`  conflicting somehow?

Error:

```
CMakeFiles/vesc_node.dir/vesc_node.cpp.o: In function rclcpp::create_subscription_factory<geometry_msgs::msg::Twist_<std::allocator<void> >, std::_Bind<void (VescNode::*(VescNode*, std::_Placeholder<1>))(std::shared_ptr<geometry_msgs::msg::Twist_<std::allocator<void> > >)>, std::allocator<void>, geometry_msgs::msg::Twist_<std::allocator<void> >, rclcpp::Subscription<geometry_msgs::msg::Twist_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<void> > >(std::_Bind<void (VescNode::*(VescNode*, std::_Placeholder<1>))(std::shared_ptr<geometry_msgs::msg::Twist_<std::allocator<void> > >)>&&, rclcpp::SubscriptionEventCallbacks const&, rclcpp::message_memory_strategy::MessageMemoryStrategy<geometry_msgs::msg::Twist_<std::allocator<void> >, std::allocator<void> >::SharedPtr, std::shared_ptr<std::allocator<void> >)::{lambda(rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rcl_subscription_options_t const&)#1}::operator()(rclcpp::node_interfaces::NodeBaseInterface*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, rcl_subscription_options_t const&) const':
vesc_node.cpp:(.text._ZZN6rclcpp27create_subscription_factoryIN13geometry_msgs3msg6Twist_ISaIvEEESt5_BindIFM8VescNodeFvSt10shared_ptrIS5_EEPS7_St12_PlaceholderILi1EEEES4_S5_NS_12SubscriptionIS5_S4_EEEENS_19SubscriptionFactoryEOT0_RKNS_26SubscriptionEventCallbacksENS_23message_memory_strategy21MessageMemoryStrategyIT2_T1_E9SharedPtrES8_ISS_EENKUlPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERK26rcl_subscription_options_tE_clESY_S16_S19_[_ZZN6rclcpp27create_subscription_factoryIN13geometry_msgs3msg6Twist_ISaIvEEESt5_BindIFM8VescNodeFvSt10shared_ptrIS5_EEPS7_St12_PlaceholderILi1EEEES4_S5_NS_12SubscriptionIS5_S4_EEEENS_19SubscriptionFactoryEOT0_RKNS_26SubscriptionEventCallbacksENS_23message_memory_strategy21MessageMemoryStrategyIT2_T1_E9SharedPtrES8_ISS_EENKUlPNS_15node_interfaces17NodeBaseInterfaceERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERK26rcl_subscription_options_tE_clESY_S16_S19_]+0x16d): undefined reference to rosidl_message_type_support_t const* rosidl_typesupport_cpp::get_message_type_support_handle<geometry_msgs::msg::Twist_<std::allocator<void> > >()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Code:
[vesc_node.cpp](https://github.com/Neuromancer2701/ROS_2_VESC_Node/blob/master/src/vesc_node/vesc_node.cpp)
[vesc_node.hpp](https://github.com/Neuromancer2701/ROS_2_VESC_Node/blob/master/src/vesc_node/vesc_node.hpp)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337781/ros2-twist-sub-linker-errors/) by [neuromancer2701](https://answers.ros.org/users/43257/neuromancer2701/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2019-11-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-17**:\

> Then that line is added back in I get all sorts of linking errors.

You can't expect us to be able to help you if you don't show those errors.

Add that information to your question text by editing it. Use the `edit` button/link.

Also show your `CMakeLists.txt` (*without* all the boilerplate comments).

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2019-11-17**:
Moreover, they have just `Twist` so unless they did a typedef / using call, then there's some problem. Moreover if they have multiple `Twist` messages defined by different packages (which the words here make me suspect) then clearly there will be a conflict.

**Comment by [neuromancer2701](https://answers.ros.org/users/43257/neuromancer2701/) on 2019-11-17**:
I did implement the code with using    `using geometry_msgs::msg::Twist;`
I just tested it without that and I still get the linker error.  Updated the question with more details and links to all the appropriate files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured out the problem.  I had added the 'geometry_msgs' to all of the places in `package.xml` and `CMakeLists.txt`
except for the dependencies line:

`ament_target_dependencies(vesc_node rclcpp std_msgs geometry_msgs)`

---

Originally posted by [neuromancer2701](https://answers.ros.org/users/43257/neuromancer2701/) with karma: 71 on 2019-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fsn9](https://answers.ros.org/users/104870/fsn9/) on 2022-05-14**:
I added that, and it worked. Thanks!

**Comment by [kimbring2](https://answers.ros.org/users/28293/kimbring2/) on 2023-02-20**:
Awsome, you save my ass.